# Async HTTP response is holding some seconds after finish the request

Tags: ios, asynchronous

The snippet of code below we ran into issues with a while ago, it is run on a successful Async HTTP response. After the response is received the user is still waiting a few seconds (or longer) before the segue is performed.

```
someService.doAction(input, callback: {
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Some-ID", sender:self)
})
```

Why was the segue not performed immediately after the HTTP response is successful?

Comment: Is the `performSegueWithIdentifier` being performed on the Main thread?

Comment: @zaph yes, it's in the main thread

Comment: you may want to show the code performing it on the mainthread, because your current code will NOT perform it on the main thread, since you run it as a callback without any idea on what thread that might happen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try call the code on the main tread:

```
someService.doAction(input, callback: {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Some-ID", sender:self)
    })
})
```